# How to pass an action to abstract parent class in C#?

Tags: c#

A basic newbie C# question.

I am trying to have an action performed when a string is edited--and I can't figure it out. The action is defined in the calling class but used by the inherited base class. Only the calling class has access to the Strings observablecollection, but it's the inherited base class that knows if an edit has been performed on the original svm.

Please help.

I am trying to do something like this without success. In the calling class,

```
 foreach (View_rx rx in rxs)
 {
    StringByColumnViewModel svm = new StringByColumnViewModel(stuff,
                    p => {
                        var oldPos = this.Strings.IndexOf(svm);  <--This is wrong
                        this.Strings.RemoveAt(oldPos);
                        this.Strings.Insert(oldPos, ???);
                    });

   Strings.Add(svm);                                       
 }
```

StringByColumnViewModel is defined like,

```
public class StringByColumnViewModel : StringViewModelBase
{

 public StringByColumnViewModel(stuff, Action<StringByColumnViewModel> OnEdit) : base()
 {
     public override void onEdit(StringViewModelBase stringViewModelBase, PrescriptionWriterViewModel returnedViewModelInstance)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
 }
}
```

At the highest level is:

```
 public abstract class StringViewModelBase     
 {

    public StringViewModelBase()
    {
        editRx = () =>
        {
            var dialog = new WindowDialog()

            ModalDialogService dialogService = new ModalDialogService();

            dialogService.ShowDialog<PrescriptionWriterViewModel>(dialog,
                new PrescriptionWriterViewModel(),

                returnedViewModelInstance =>
                {
                    if (dialog.DialogResult.HasValue && dialog.DialogResult.Value)
                    {
                        onEdit(this, returnedViewModelInstance);
                    }
                });
        };

 public abstract void onEdit(StringViewModelBase stringViewModelBase, PrescriptionWriterViewModel returnedViewModelInstance);
 }
```

So how is this done?  All help is appreciated.

Trying to be more clear, in short when svm is created:

```
StringByColumnViewModel svm = new StringByColumnViewModel( someaction);
```

I would like to pass the action to be done, someaction, on svm creation such that when the lambda expression in the base class is true that action will be performed. The action to be performed is to remove the current svm from Strings and replace it with another svm. So the problem is passing one lamda expression to be used by another.

Any ideas? Or is this approach just totally wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering what part you are stuck on here - the `onEdit` or the invoking of an action after `onEdit` is c alled?  Consider implementing the `IObservable<T>` interface instead of trying to do some magic with abstract base classes.

Comment: Unclear.  Hard to tell wth is going on.  Can you create a *minimal, correct example* of what you're trying to do?  I just don't see it buried under all the production code.

Comment: @Will Essentially, I am trying to provide the action to be taken from the calling class to replace/become the onEdit action that is performed in the abstract class StringViewModelBase when the HasValue && Value are true. Can't get the syntax.

Comment: @DanPantry Ideally, I would like to replace the "onEdit" with the action specified from the calling class. But I am trying to keep Strings only in the calling class.

Comment: @DanPantry  I amended the question for clarity (I hope). Thanks.

Comment: I'll asnwer this on my lunch break

Comment: Nope, still don't understand.  Hope Dan helps you.  In future, http://www.sscce.org/ a little effort to get to the core of the issue, stripping away everything that's not necessary, can result in a quick answer to your problems.

Comment: @Will LOL! I don't know enough to phrase the question correctly. My current solution raises an event when the DialogResult returns true. The subscriber to the event in the calling code then performs the action of removing one svm and adding the new one back to Strings. I was trying to avoid the whole event thing and simply have a true DialogResult perform the same action--a action passed in by the calling method. I hope that's better. (Its hard to do sscce.org when you don't know what to do). Thanks though. I have a lot to learn.

Comment: @DanPantry Would posting my current solution using events help any?

Comment: I didn't get around to answering this yesterday. I'll try today :) sorry. Your comment clarifies things enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I am correct, you are trying to figure out how to pass an action to the constructor of an object that should be executed when the object's `OnEdit` event is fired, but that the action needs to maintain a reference to the modified object itself. To immediately resolve your issue, simply change your first code sample so that it doesn't require `svm` from the lexical scope but instead requires a view model passed in via a parameter, like this.

```
 foreach (View_rx rx in rxs)
 {
    StringByColumnViewModel svm = new StringByColumnViewModel(stuff,
                    stringByColViewModel, presenterViewModel => {
                        var oldPos = this.Strings.IndexOf(stringByColViewModel);  <--This is wrong
                        this.Strings.RemoveAt(oldPos);
                        this.Strings.Insert(oldPos, ???);
                    });

   Strings.Add(svm);                                       
 }

 public class StringByColumnViewModel
 {
     public StringByColumnViewModel(Action<StringByColumnViewModelBase> onEdit) : base(onEdit)
     }
 }
```

I would however suggest not doing this. This is mainly a matter of separation of concerns. To me, your `StringByColumnViewModel` should not be coupled to an `OnEdit` implementation. If you do this, then you are telling me that `StringByColumnViewModel` is a view model that holds data but also has the responsibility of knowing what it should do when it is edited.

The approach which I would highly recommend is the observer pattern. `OnEdit` is a very 'Observer-y' name, in that you are observing that the model has changed. By requiring the `Action` in the class you are saying that you *must* react to it changing, one way or another, and I think you'll find that with this approach you will just end up with lots of `() => {}` added to fulfill those constraints. Instead, you should try using the `IObserver<T>` interface.

It would look something like this.

```
foreach(var rx in rxs)
{
    var viewModel = new StringByColumnViewModel(stuff);
    // You could use either IObserver<T> or standard .NET events here
    // I'm using IObserver<T> because you can use interesting libraries
    // with it (namely Reactive Extensions) but both uses are valid
    viewModel.Edited.Subscribe(stringByColViewModel => OnHandleEdit(stringByColViewModel));
    Strings.Add(viewModel);
}

protected void OnHandleEdit(StringByColViewModel stringByColViewModel)
{
    var position = Strings.IndexOf(stringByColViewModel);
    Strings.RemoveAt(position);
    Strings.Insert(position, stringByColViewModel);
}
```

Although it is worth nothing that as far as I know, you don't need to remove/insert from `Strings` because `StringByColumnViewModel` is a reference type. Any changes on `StringByColumnViewModel`, `Strings` will already be aware of them as it holds a reference to the instance of `StringByColumnViewModel`.

If you do continue with the approach of `Strings` modification, make sure to take care of concurrency issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and mentoring. This is great!

Comment: It's fine. Note that my observer example may not work if you don't have ReactiveExtensions installed. `IObserver<T>` is part of the CLR but the extension method `IObserver<T>.Subscribe(Action<T>)` is not.

Comment: Just installed ReactiveExtensions from nugget. How do you define the "Edited" extension? Thanks.